# GET request with emojis on url fails: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, character-encoding

I am trying to make a request using `requests` module in python.

```py
import requests
url = "https://www.foo.bar/topic/512174-some-text-�-text-some-�☀️/"
r=requests.get(url)
```

I have tried both python 3.11.0 and 3.7.3 with `requests` version 2.30.0 and 2.25.1 respectively.

The source web is a forum which lists threads whose raw html looks something like this

`https://www.foo.bar/topic/1234567-✅-some-text-✅/`

## Approach #1

When first feeding manually this url to requests, there are some encoding issues as the request cannot be carried out:
`'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 35-37: invalid continuation byte`.

## Approach #2

When getting the url form the source as stated before, I first decode in `utf-8` before passing it to `requests` and I see it's doing something like this:
`https://www.foo.bar/topic/1234567-�-some-text-��/`

and still failing.

## Approach #3

I've tried switching the encoding when fetching the url to `latin-1` but the previous characters cannot be decoded either.

## Approach #4

Then I tried using the `quote` method to escape some characters on the url before passing it to `requests` but I see it's translating some characters differently as a browser should do, in any way, it's still failing.

---

headers used in the request:

```py
headers = {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
}
```

Is there a different approach when feeding `requests` url with emojis or weird characters on it?

Edit 1: adding info from comments

Requests seems to be ok when feeding it emojis that are percent encoded, however I came across this case

This is taken from the raw html: `www.foo.bar/topic/123123-some-text-�--text-some-�☀️/` I tried using the `quote` method from `urllib` to percent encode and it comes out as this: `https://www.foo.bar/topic/1233123-some-text-%EF%BF%BD-text-some-%EF%BF%BD%E2%98%80%EF%B8%8F`

My best guess is that there are some new emojis that are created with a different encoding and a that's why it's getting messed up?

Comment: if you could post the code snippet, it'd be easier for us to reproduce

Comment: It was a manual GET request to the url with some emojis, I added a small snippet

Comment: In your question, you posted that the URL has these green check marks but they appear as question marks. The green check marks seem to get percent-encoded to sequences of `%E2%9C%85`. 
If you or see question mark "emojis", it might be due to how and where you copied and pasted the URL from.
If you replace the sequences `%EF%BF%BD` with the other here, does it start to work?

Comment: The URL I used in my answer showed correctly in the browser but was already percent-encoded when I pasted it from the browser's address bar to my Visual Studio Code, for example. I am using UTF-8 encoding for all source files, by default.

Comment: @JarnoLamberg In the source html, they appear as green marks for me and when copying pasting they are encoded, that's true. Both work for me on my browser and requests.

Now for this one `https://www.foo.bar/topic/512174-some-text-�-text-some-�☀️/` it already appears as a question mark on the source html and for my browser it works, but not for requests.

Comment: With Requests, I started getting an HTTP 403 with this latest URL but for the real domain, and also for the URL that has the question mark and sun emojis percent_encoded. The page has the message `Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue` presumably because of the captcha.
But at least the URL is working as Requests can read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special characters such as emojis in URLs, in URL paths to be more exact, need to be [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding).

Requests should be happy if you percent-encoded the check marks in your URL before passing it to Requests. (I tried with a different URL that had hearts in it that Requests accepted when percent-encoded.)

Your question shows the URL with green check mark emojis that should be percent-encoded as sequences of `%E2%9C%85` each. Yet, in your code the URL has question mark emojis (placeholders for unrecognized characters) instead of the check marks.

Some terminals and editors might not be configured to show Unicode characters correctly, by default. You might want to check your settings for that.

Comment: The URL I used was `https://techmighty.in/%E2%9D%A4-emoji-use-in-domain-name-or-urls-of-website-%E2%9D%A4/` in encoded form, and `https://techmighty.in/❤-emoji-use-in-domain-name-or-urls-of-website-❤/` in decoded form. I am not affiliated to that website in any way.

Comment: Yeah I also noticed that for emojis it tends to work. I found this one and `requests` fails. This is taken from the raw html:

https://www.foo.bar/topic/123123-some-text-�--text-some-�☀️/

I tried using the `quote`method from `urllib` to percent encode and it comes out as this:

https://www.foo.bar/topic/1233123-some-text-%EF%BF%BD-text-some-%EF%BF%BD%E2%98%80%EF%B8%8F

My best guess is that there are some new emojis that are created with a different encoding and a that's why it's getting messed up?

Comment: I am only encoding the path, that's correct. For the previous url it is encoding it like this:

`https://www.foo.bar/topic/1233123-some-text-%EF%BF%BD-text-some-%EF%BF%BD%E2%98%80%EF%B8%8F`

The error I am getting is 

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 48-50: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: I just updated my answer with a suggestion. Does that help?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: I provided 2 examples, the one with the green marks is one of them, and that works fine with the suggestions you provided.  
The second one with the question marks is another example taken from my browser which does not work on requests

Comment: The thing is, if I try to percent encode the url with question marks, it is done like so:

`https://www.foo.bar/topic/1233123-some-text-%EF%BF%BD-text-some-%EF%BF%BD%E2%98%80%EF%B8%8F` but on the browser it is encoded differently:

`https://www.foo.bar/topic/1233123-some-text-%F0%9F%92-text-some-%B8%E2%98%80%EF%B8%8F/` 

So I don't really know how this was encoded but I can't percent encode the characters as the browser does

Comment: I noticed that the server behind the real URL and not the www.foo.bar does not care whether it has the full percent-encoded URL path as long as the `/topic/512174-some-text` part is there, at least when testing with a browser. With Requests, HTTPie, or cURL, however, that shorter path does not seem to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253565/discussion-between-emilio-cea-and-jarno-lamberg).

Comment: So unless the `requests` team does anything on their part regarding the issues they have opened for this matter, I guess it's safe to assume we can close this for the time being, thanks a lot @jarno